# message: "string.substitute could not find key \"loadingState\" in template" esri javascript 3.23

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to add a measure widget from the esri samples and I get the following error.
[image: error message]

I am using boostrap.css and I am wondering if this has an effect on widget loading.

`<div class="container-fluid" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false">`

I am also wondering if these tags conflict with each other. I have trouble getting widgets to show in my map div.

`<div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" class="is">`

I toggle the classes to change the page width and show a side bar menu.

I saw a similar question with no answer.

Comment: What was the similar question that you saw?  Please always provide a link when referencing another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message of `string.substitute could not find key "loadingState" in template` actually refers to a missing variable in the function that is using the ["ContentPane" widget](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html).

Take this method that will attempt to load the "dijit/layout/ContentPane" using the parser:

`require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (parser) {
        parser.parse();
});`

SOLUTION, add a variable for the missing "loadingState":

`require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (parser) {
        loadingState = "Loading";
        parser.parse();
});`